# Check if textbox is checked before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I want to submit the form if and only if the textbox is checked... if not I want to stop the form and give an alert

Right now I am getting the alert if it is not checked but it's submitting the form either way

```
$(function() {
        $("#button").click(function(){
        if ($("#uploadTOS").is(":checked")) {
        return true;
        } else {
        alert("Please agree to the TOS");
        return false;
        }
        })
        })

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="urlupload.php?do=verify" id="form" method="post" onsubmit="a=document.getElementById('form').style;a.display='none';b=document.getElementById('part2').style;b.display='inline';" style="display: inline;">
<div id="uploadform">
<input type="text" name="uploadfile" size="30" /><p>
<input type="submit" id="button" class="button" value="Upload" />
</div>
        <div id="TOSDiv" style="display:none; z-index:60;">
            <input id="uploadTOS" type="checkbox" name="tos" value="1" />
            <span id="uploadTOSText">
                I Agree to the <a href="tos.php" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>
            </span>     
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SFsKL/1/

Comment: for some reason my form is still submitting either way

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SFsKL/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onclick javascript with this:

```
function toscheck() {

        if ($("#uploadTOS").is(":checked")) {
        return true;
        } else {
        alert("Please agree to the TOS");
        return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change javascript to:

```
function submitcheck() {

        if ($("#uploadTOS").is(":checked")) {
        return true;
        } else {
        alert("Please agree to the TOS");
        return false;
        }
}
```

And then add onclick to the submit button

```
<input type="submit" id="button" class="button" value="Upload" onclick="return submitcheck();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe return values are deprecated for newer versions of jQuery. Try [`event.preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) instead of `return false`.

Note that the `event` variable would simply by the first argument to your jQuery `.click(function(event) {...})` handler.